# how to ignore ESAPI exception "org.owasp.esapi.errors.IntrusionException: Input validation failure"?

Tags: java, owasp, esapi

My project (built on JSP,Struts,hibernate) takes an input from user and saves it in the database. To make my application secure I have used ESAPI jar.

I am getting exception

> org.owasp.esapi.errors.IntrusionException: Input validation failure

at the method `ESAPI.encoder().canonicalize();`

This exception is generally coming when we are copying and pasting data from skype,MS word etc.

When I copy paste the string from skype messenger it automatically adds extra styling data with div,meta,p,etc (all the HTML tags) which leads to addition of many special characters which might be causing the exception mentioned above.

But when I copy the string from notepad it doesn't give an exception.

How can I ignore this exception so that I can add the data ? is there something to be modified in ESAPI.properties or validation.properties? what are your views?

Answer (score 0):

I think your weird issue has to do with additional encoding when you paste something from (say) MS Word versus from something simple like notepad. When you are in Word, it picks up some additional meta-data and the default 'paste' from 'MS Word' is really 'paste special'. This is done so that you can copy text from one Office application to another (e.g., Word to Outlook) and "retain formatting". I think it is all this additional meta-data that you are getting that is messing you up, because it probably looks to ESAPI like it is multi-encoded or it thinks that mixed-encoding is used.

That said,if you want to do validation, you really ought to be using one of the Validator.isValidInput() or Validator.getValidInput() methods. This call Encoder.canonicalize() by default (unless you use the latest ESAPI from the 'develop' branch, where you can actually disable the canonicalization--a recent bug fix).

-kevin